# Windows batch script dont work in task scheduler

Tags: windows

I am trying to get the below script to work as bat file in Windows 2012 Task Scheduler. The task runs and nothing happens, no errors in history. It works if i run it from command prompt with one less "%" and if i double click on the bat file. This is to copy *.bak files from folder/sub folders structure to destination UNC path.

FOR /r "Source folder" %%G in (*.bak) DO @copy "%%G" "\destination UNC path"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps instead of having the task scheduler running the batch file directly you should have it run `cmd /c file.bat`

Comment: I tried and it worked. Did you specify the full path for the source folder, and not relative to the batch file? (The task's working directory is `C:\Windows\system32`). Does the user that runs the task have permission to that UNC path?

Comment: Thank you Jerry and Andrew for the fast reply. I have manage to fix it by scheduling this as Jerry suggested. Relay appreciate your help.